# Int converted from InputField text not updating when typing numbers in the InputField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a converting button and I need the user to specify the amount of currency that they want to convert to with numbers but when I type in a number inside the InputField the variable does not change.If you can help me that would be great.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int d;
    public InputField convertInput;

    void Start()
    {
        int d = int.Parse("0"+convertInput.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start is called only once, when the object is instantiated, you should move that code to Update() or better use onValueChanged event from InputField like that:

```
void Start(){
    convertInput.onValueChanged.AddListener(HandleValueChanged);
}

void HandleValueChanged(string newValue){
    int d = int.Parse("0"+newValue);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you this worked i just thought that the Parse would work for every frame not just the start.